# How I can managing container registries with registries.conf?

Tags: spring, docker, podman

I am new to Docker. And I'm trying to do this example from the book "Spring in action":

```
~$ docker run --name my-cassandra \--network cassandra-net \-p 9042:9042 \-d cassandra:latest
```

And I have this:

Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create `/etc/containers/nodocker` to quiet msg.
Error: short-name "cassandra:latestc" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if the mistake is in your original command or the pasting. I think it should be "cassandra" with two "ss" characters. Also the error you have posted mentions "latestc" which looks like a mistake too.

Comment: Yes, "cassandra" with "ss", but it doesn't work too.